# How do you pass in the username from the login page and make it appear on the sidebar

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to incorporate the user userID on the sidebar.

So the sidebar will show "Welcome username"

I've tried the cookie method but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my cookie receiving my username:

```
def login_user(request):
    state = "Please log in below..."
    username = password = ''
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                state = "You're successfully logged in!"
                cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
                cookie['username']=str(time.time())
                return render_to_response('r2/topic/index.html',{})
            else:
                state = "Your account is not active, please contact the site admin."
        else:
            state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."
            return render_to_response('registration/login.html',{'state':state, 'username': username})

    return render_to_response('registration/login.html',{'state':state, 'username': username})
```

and this is my index.html:

```
                  <!-- sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar">
            <div class="about-me">
                <h3>Welcome {{ username }}</h3> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function getCookie(c_name)
        {
          var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
          for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
            {
                x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
                y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
                x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
                if (x==c_name)
                    {
                        return unescape(y);
                    }
            }
        }


        function checkCookie()
        {
          var username=getCookie("username");
          if (username!=null && username!="")
            {

                <h3>document.getElementById("about-me").innerHTML = "Welcome " +username;</h3>
            }
          else 
            {
                username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
                if (username!=null && username!="")
                        {
                            setCookie("username",username,365);
                        }
            }
        }
        </script>
```

Am i doing anything wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: whats `<h3>document.getElementById("about-me").innerHTML = "Welcome " +username;</h3>` about try removing the header tags

Comment: tried that and it still didn't show the username

Comment: I believe you have machine detectable errors in your JS

Comment: Robus what kind of machine detecable errors am i looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why so complicated? 
You can check if user is logged in directly in  template:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
   Hello {{ user.username }}
{% else %}
   Please log in
{% endif %}
```

And check that in settings.py in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS have 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth'. Here is some [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth)

Comment: So Denis, i just need to add that in my index.html file?

Comment: Yes, and don't forget add to render_to_responce context_instance=RequestContext(request). Here is more [info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response)

Comment: ok Thanks everyone especially Denis! i managed to get it to show the username. Thank you. :D

Comment: Don't forget to approve the answer and Happy New year! =)

Comment: happy new year to you too! :D

Comment: sorry how do i go about doing that? i'm new to stack overflow. I wanted to accept yours.